# Oracle: prioritizing results based on column’s value

Tags: oracle

I have a data-set in which there are duplicate IDs in the first column. I'm hoping to obtain a single row of data for each ID based on the second column's value. The data looks like so:

```
ID   Info_Source   Prior?
A        1           Y
A        3           N
A        2           Y
B        1           N
B        1           N
B        2           Y
C        2           N
C        3           Y
C        1           N
```

Specifically the criteria would call for prioritizing based on the second column's value (3 highest priority; then 1; and lastly 2): if the 'Info_Source' column has a value of 3, return that row; if there is no 3 in the second column for a given ID, look for a 1 and if found return that row; and finally if there is no 3 or 1 associated with the ID, search for 2 and return that row for the ID.

The desired results would be a single row for each ID, and the resulting data would be:

```
ID   Info_Source   Prior?
A        3           N
B        1           N
C        3           Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row_number() over() usually solves these needs nicely and efficiently e.g.

```
select ID, Info_Source, Prior
from (
      select ID, Info_Source, Prior
      , row_number() over(partition by id order by Info_source DESC) as rn
     )
where rn = 1
```

For prioritizing the second column's value (3 ; then 1, then 2) use a case expression to alter the raw value into an order that you need.

```
select ID, Info_Source, Prior
from (
      select ID, Info_Source, Prior
      , row_number() over(partition by id 
                          order by case when Info_source = 3 then 3
                                        when Infor_source = 1 then 2
                                        else 1 end DESC) as rn
     )
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked. I figured the answer existed somewhere between partitioning and using a case statement, I just couldn't realize how to combine the two. I appreciate the quick help.